# DAX previous non empty day

Tags: dax

Sorry if I missed similar question/answer.

Basically I am trying to do a day to day comparison in DAX, but cannot find a  good way to get the measure for previous non empty day.

I tried PREVIOUSDAY function, but when there is a gap in days, for instance, if there is no sale on Sat & Sun, the result is not what I need

```
PreviousAmount = CALCULATE([Total $ Amount], PREVIOUSDAY('Fact'[Date]))
```

What I can think of is to add a helper column in the date dimension to indicate previous non empty date (i.e. if the date is Monday, then previous non empty date will be previous Friday). Then I can use CALCULATE function and filter by the non empty date.

But instead of doing that, is there any way to do the calculation on the fly? Thanks in advance.

Below table should reflect what I want to achieve:

```html
<table border="1">
    <th>Date</th><th>Amount</th><th>What I got</th><th>What I hope</th>
    <tr>
      <td>01/07/2016</td>
      <td>7983</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>04/07/2016</td>
      <td>15933</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>7983</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
  <tr>
      <td>05/07/2016</td>
      <td>38591</td>
      <td>15933</td>
      <td>15933</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>06/07/2016</td>
      <td>7859</td>
      <td>38591</td>
    <td>38591</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>07/07/2016</td>
      <td>3252</td>
      <td>7859</td>
    <td>7859</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>07/07/2016</td>
      <td>9474</td>
      <td>3252</td>
    <td>3252</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the neatest but you can create a calculated column to store the previous day value

```
PreviousDate =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( [Date] ),
    FILTER ( AmountTable, AmountTable[Date] < EARLIER ( AmountTable[Date] ) )
)
```

and then create a new calculated column for the amount for that previous day

```
=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( [Amount] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( AmountTable ),
        AmountTable[Date] = EARLIER ( AmountTable[PreviousDate] )
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks for the comments. However when I applied EARLIER function the engine returns error "Earlier refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist"

Comment: Hi - could you have added these as measures instead of calculated columns? These formulas are for calculated columns for a table with a date field and an amount field. Calculated columns work row by row. EARLIER will refer to the original row value, before FILTER is applied.